# Response for X-ray import using cucumber JSON is not as expected using v1.0

Tags: cucumber, jira-rest-api, jira-xray

I am trying to import Cucumber/Karate test execution in JSON format but the response is not as expected and doesn't import it in X-ray test execution

The response I get when I import the json is

```
{"testExecIssue": {
    "id": "some number",
    "key": "XXXXXX-123",
    "self": "https://<jira host>/rest/api/2/issue/4611911"
  },
  "infoMessages": []
}
```

I was expecting "testIssues" and success keys in the JSON response

Comment: Did my answer clarify your question? If so, can you please mark it as correct? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using Xray on Jira server/datacenter, right?

The expected response for the Cucumber JSON endpoint on Xray on Jira server/datacenter is detailed on the [API documentation](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST#ImportExecutionResultsREST-CucumberJSONresults) and returns just the Test Execution issue, similarly to the following snippet:

```
{
    "testExecIssue": {
           "id": "10000",
           "key": "DEMO-123",
           "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/10000"
     }
}
```

Test issues are not returned as they are not updated nor created; Xray only reports the results against the existing Test issues.

Note: if you were using Xray on Jira cloud, the response would be slightly different as detailed on [Xray Cloud REST API documentation](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST+v2#ImportExecutionResultsRESTv2-CucumberJSONresults).